# What is zero-byte executable files in Windows

Tags: windows, executable

I've noticed some zero-bytes executable in folder %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps created during install some applications. What are they? How can I create and call it in the same way as Windows does? Thank you.

`GameBarElevatedFT_Alias.exe      0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
kali.exe                         0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
x410.exe                         0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
Alpine.exe                       0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
archlinux.exe                    0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
MicrosoftEdge.exe                0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
ubuntu.exe                       0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
wt.exe                           0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
Slack.exe                        0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
python.exe                       0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
python3.exe                      0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
fedoraremix.exe                  0 C:\Users\nguyenc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`

Comment: This is a special type of app-execution reparse point that's used to set up the security context for running a UWP app. `CreateProcessW` reparses this internally in order to allow individual users to run a particular app.

Comment: To display the raw reparse point buffer for "python.exe", run `fsutil reparsepoint query %localappdata%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`.

Answer (score 20):

These are execution aliases for MS Store apps.
You can manage it in Settings > Apps > Apps & features > App execution aliases.
[image: App execution aliases]

Comment: Strange, didn't know this. I had the problem that Windows won't start these apps (from `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` after an Windows update. Turning them off and on again in the `App execution aliases` did the trick!

Comment: Same problem, same solution!  Ubuntu executable that worked last week stopped.  I had to reboot in between turning the aliases off and on, but now they work.  (And File Explorer still shows them as 0-length.)  But all good now.  Thanks thatfellowoveryonder and @Xairoo

Comment: Regarding these "execution alias" things... I'm curious if anyone knows?  Why didn't MS just use regular hard links or symbolic links for this stuff?  

NTFS has them right? (which obviously MS would have implemented into NTFS themselves)

Why create some additional non-standard to do exactly the same thing?  ...only in a less standard/compatible way.

Comment: Yes, i confirm tuning on and off aliases and, after that, restarting os did  the trick

Comment: Ran into this on a Win-11 machine also.  Trying to install Python3 and found these strange 0-length .exe's in c:\Home\<myuserid>\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps which is hidden directory.  When you enter "Python3" at Cmd-prompt, the MS trick is not just to set security context, but also to fling up a Microsoft Store panel to induce user to load Python and Python-tools (which cost money, of course) from the Microsoft Store.  Hilarious.  I want to install Python, in a C:\Python directory,  NOT as an UWP app.  Possible?  And is it possible to remove completely the UWP/WIndowsApp stuff?