# opening RStudio generates a 0 kb git.exe file

Tags: r, windows, rstudio

I am using R Studio 2022.02.3 Build 492 with R 4.2.0 -- "Vigorous Calisthenics" on a Win 10 PC.

When I double click on a R file, i.e. a R script, R studio opens and a 0 KB git.exe file is generated in the folder where my .R file was located.

I can not find any relevant information about this (my searches points towards using Git from RStudio). This started yesterday without any conscious change from my part and updating R and RStudio did not help.

- Is this something I should be worried about?
- How can stop this from happening?

Some more system info/specification:

- it is a git.exe file (0 KB). Nor a git folder or anything else.
- Date/time of git.exe (as shown in windows explorer) is similar to when I double click on the .R file
- R is in its default place: Windows/Program files/R
- RStudio is in its default place: Windows/Program files/RStudio
- In RStudion, Git/SVN options are default, i.e.: Git executable: (Not Found); SVN executable (Not Found), SSH RSA key: (None)

Comment: Is this relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/58296925/2554330 ?

Comment: Where are your R files located? What do the options in your RStudio...Global Options...Git SVN settings? Do you have an `.Rprofile` file that runs any code when RStudio starts up? And you are sure it's a `git.exe` file and not a `.git` folder or something like that? Does the file have a created by date that matches up to when you opened the file?

Comment: Thanks user2554330. I am not sure. R or RStudio are not displayed in the App execution aliases window.

Comment: Thanks for comment MrFlick, main question is now edited to answers those points