# Error when opening Windows Terminal to "Ubuntu"

Tags: ubuntu, windows-terminal

I just installed windows-terminal on windows 10,

I get the following error when trying to open windows terminal to ubuntu - I do indeed have WSL2 installed and can use it from the ubuntu app standalone terminal, but for whatever reason windows terminal is having an issue

I've searched online and it appears that something is wrong with finding the executable, but I cannot figure out where to make an update to assist windows terminal with knowing the correct path

`[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching 'ubuntu.exe']`

[image]

While troubleshooting, I learned that `ws -v` is not a recognized command while trying to get more information for this post, so I ran `SFC /scannow` following [this advice](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-cant-find-wt-exe-fix/), but unfortunately no progress made, errors still taking place

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Solved by adding `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` to PATH

Comment: from cmd prompt:

```set WSLPATH=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
set PATH=%WSLPATH%;%PATH%```

Comment: I also had to re-open Windows Terminal after adding the directory to my PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

For me, issue was solved via restart of PC and toggling on and off 'App execution aliases' in settings. Guide to do this in below forum.

[What is zero-byte executable files in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296925/what-is-zero-byte-executable-files-in-windows)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35177400)

Answer (score 0):

I write this answer for WSL2 installed on windows 10

1. Go to the terminal settings.(shortcut key- ctrl+,)
2. If the navigation panel is shrink then Clicked on the 3 line icon on the left side top of the window
3. In navigation panel clicked on the Ubuntu icon
4. Here you can see "Command line" card and clicked on down arrow and change it (if it is wsl.exe) change it to ubuntu.exe
   4.at very bottom of the "Command line card"  you can see "starting directory" card.
5. Clicked drop down arrow on it and change it value in to "~". To represent home directory.
   6.Then save the changes and relaunch terminal app.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and click on the Ubuntu icon left side. Then click on the Command line row and change your path to like this format:

```
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix **[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `ubuntu.exe']** :-

Step 1 : Open command prompt. Then click on down arrow button then click on
settings.
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EVyT.png)

Step 2 : Select Ubuntu from left panel. Click on Command line option.
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr5aT.png)

Step 3 : Change ubuntu.exe file name to **wsl.exe** and save.
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Ldk.png)

Step 4 : Close the command prompt and reopen it. Now Ubuntu can be opened in command prompt.